# Bind a dropdown box selection to an Id of another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a object list `admins` which contains a `Username` and `Id` property. Within a `dropdown`, I only display the `Username` property. If the user now selects an admin, I want to store the `Id` (not the username) into another object `settings`:

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<select class="input-large" ng-model="vm.settings.selectedAdminId">
    <option ng-repeat="admin in vm.admins | orderBy:'Username'">{{admin.Username}}</option>
</select>
```

I am able to select a Username but I don't know how to store the selected `admin.Id` into `settings.selectedAdminId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). Then it will be

```
<select class="input-large" 
    ng-model="vm.settings.selectedAdminId"
    ng-options="admin.Id as admin.Username for admin in vm.admins | orderBy:'Username'">
</select>
```

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('DemoController', function() {
  this.admins = [
    {Id: 123, Username: 'Thomas'},
    {Id: 344, Username: 'Mann'}
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController as vm">
  <select class="input-large" 
    ng-model="vm.settings.selectedAdminId" 
    ng-options="admin.Id as admin.Username for admin in vm.admins | orderBy:'Username'">
  </select>
  
  <p>Selected: {{ vm.settings.selectedAdminId }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats even nicer. Im new to angular and so impressed every day :-). I will accept the answer in 4 min.

Comment: Not only this is nicer, but this is how it should be, given that with ngRepeat you might encounter certain problems. See this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482912/bind-a-dropdown-box-selection-to-an-id-of-another-object/37483009#comment62462739_37482973).

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```
<select class="input-large" ng-model="vm.settings.selectedAdminId">
    <option ng-repeat="admin in vm.admins | orderBy:'Username'" value="{{admin.Id}}">{{admin.Username}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thanks a lot! Is this the way to go when having a list of possible values and I need to store the selected one?

Comment: You can also use $index if the object itself doesnt have an id.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Avoid using ngRepeat to render select options. You can't bind ngModel to object (for example to entire `admin` object rather than `Id`), ngRepeat create child scope for every option tag, which is redundant and has performance implications. Finally, you won't be able to set up selected admin if you tried `this.settings.selectedAdminId = 123` - it won't set option selected.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks for that hint.

Comment: @dfsq absolutly +1